3D segmentation mask bounding box and removal of unwanted voxels
I have a 3D segmentation mask, and I want to resize it to the dimensions of the ROI and remove the unwanted voxels around it.
This is my code for creating the 3D bounding box around the region but it's not working
# import libraries 
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def bounding_box_3d(image, segmentation): 
    """ Draws the 3d bounding box around the segmented region in the image"""
    # Get the coordinates of the segmented region
    coords = np.where(segmentation)
    # Get the min and max coordinates for each dimension
    min_coords = np.min(coords, axis=1)
    max_coords = np.max(coords, axis=1) + 1  # Add 1 because slicing is exclusive at the upper bound
    # Draw the bounding box on the image
    image[min_coords[0]:max_coords[0], min_coords[1], min_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0]:max_coords[0], max_coords[1], min_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0]:max_coords[0], min_coords[1], max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0]:max_coords[0], max_coords[1], max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0], min_coords[1]:max_coords[1], min_coords[2]] = 1
    image[max_coords[0], min_coords[1]:max_coords[1], min_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0], min_coords[1]:max_coords[1], max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[max_coords[0], min_coords[1]:max_coords[1], max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0], min_coords[1], min_coords[2]:max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[max_coords[0], min_coords[1], min_coords[2]:max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[min_coords[0], max_coords[1], min_coords[2]:max_coords[2]] = 1
    image[max_coords[0], max_coords[1], min_coords[2]:max_coords[2]] = 1
    return image

# Call the function with an image nii and the segmentation
image = nib.load('/Tr_0351_0000.nii.gz')
image_data = image.get_fdata()
# Load segmentation 
segmentation = nib.load('/Tr_0351.nii.gz')
segmentation_data = segmentation.get_fdata()
# Apply function and visualize
image_data = bounding_box_3d(image_data, segmentation_data)
plt.imshow(image_data[:, :, 50], cmap='gray')
plt.show()



